# javac error while executing Java with Spring console based application

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to execute a Java with Spring application from console/DOS prompt. Here are the steps I've followed:

1. Downloaded spring-framework-3.1.0.RELEASE and unzipped it as well.
2. Created a folder called 'springlib' on F:.
3. Copied all the files under the folder - F:\spring-framework-3.1.0.RELEASE\dist to F:\springlib
4. Copied all the files under the folder - F:\spring-framework-3.1.0.RELEASE\projects\spring-build\lib\ivy to F:\springlib
5. Created a folder F:\springtest and placed below Java program in it:

   import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

   public class BillRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        System.out.println(context);
     }
   }
6. Tried to compile the program as shown below:

   F:\springtest>javac -cp F:\springlib* BillRunner.java
   javac: invalid flag: F:\springlib\commons-httpclient.jar
   Usage: javac  
   use -help for a list of possible options
7. Why am I getting such error? What is the solution?

Comment: What's inside the `springlib` directory? jars?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be due to the way you declare your classpath :-cp F:\springlib*
Maybe you could try this `F:\springtest>javac -cp "F:\springlib\*" BillRunner.java` but I must admit it still has to be tested.
More info on problems related to wildcards in a classpath [here](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/07/jdk-6-supports-in-classpath-but-be.html)

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Still the same error:F:\springtest>javac -cp "F:\springlib\*" BillRunner.java
javac: invalid flag: F:\springlib\commons-httpclient.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: Yes, of course. No idea why the backslash didn't show above. I've tried your suggestion exactly the way you said.